# Why was the Equity of Redemption = property worth — still owing mortgage debt? And not only the latter?

Tags: mortgage

Source: [*Introduction to Law in Canada*](http://emond.ca/introduction-to-law-in-canada.html) (2014). pp. 288 Bottom - 289 Top.

> In simplified terms, a **mortgage** is a kind of charge against land that secures a debt owed 
>   by the landowner. The modern concept of a mortgage differs from the traditional concept.
>
> Traditionally, a mortgage involved transferring the landowner's title to the land to the lend- 
>   er. The lender would hold this title as security against the loan, with a promise to transfer 
>   title back to the owner once the latter had repaid the mortgage loan in full. If the owner/borrower (the mortgagor) missed a payment or otherwise went into default, the lender (the 
>   mortgagee, often a bank) was entitled to keep the land unconditionally. However, in equity, the mortgagor was given a period of time to come up with the balance—in other words, 
>   a redemption period (see the discussion of the Court of Chancery, in Chapter 2). The owner's right to redeem his property came to be known as the mortgagor's "equity of redemption"; `it was valued at the worth of the property minus the amount of the mortgage debt still 
>   owing.` Hence we now refer to a property owner's "equity" in the property, which refers to 
>   the net market value of his unencumbered interest in the property.

Why wasn't the Equity of Redemption instead only `the amount of the mortgage debt still 
owing`? This is what the mortgagor must pay, NOT the sentence coloured in gray.

Comment: Your equity isn't how much you *owe*; it's how much you *own*.

Comment: If you own a property worth $600,000 with a $200,000 mortgage, then you could sell for $600,000, pay back the $200,000 and walk away with $400,000. The $400,000 is your equity. The higher the value, the higher the equity. The higher the mortgage, the lower the equity.

Answer (score 1):

The **equity of redemption** is the right to pay off the mortgage balance.

The **value of the equity of redemption** to the person obligated on the mortgage, a.k.a. the **equity** in the property, is the value of the property less the amount of the mortgage.